# how to make pyspark - in windows command prompt - run jupyter notebook

Tags: windows, pyspark

I have anaconda python running Jupyter perfectly
i have Hadoop, yarn and spark running on windows 10 cmd perfectly. I changed a lot of variables in the system of windows but now works fine

when running PySpark, it works

but I want to start Jupyter notebook when I run PySpark on cmd, and cannot

Comment: The only windows system variables that I have changed and successfully made the pyspark under cmd is as follows: Var Name: PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and Var Value: C:\Users\Mostafa\Anaconda3\python.exe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, go on powershell change this env variables.

```
$env:PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
$env:PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

or CMD

```
SET PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

and then run pyspark, it will automatically execute your jupyter notebook.

Comment: This is what happened when : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mostafa\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main